# Why is python giving large errors when dividing the results of sin()

Tags: python, rounding-error

I was trying to find the values for the first ten integer inputs of n for an equation I found: `x = sin(2π / n) / sin(π / n)`. The output I got from the code I wrote to find them was quite surprising:

```
>>> for i in range(1, 11):
        print math.sin(2 * math.pi / i) / math.sin(math.pi / i)

-2.0
1.22464679915e-16
1.0
1.41421356237
1.61803398875
1.73205080757
1.8019377358
1.84775906502
1.87938524157
1.90211303259
```

I realise that there will be rounding errors, and as such the following results don't surprise me at all:

```
>>> math.sin(2 * math.pi)
-2.4492935982947064e-16
>>> math.sin(math.pi)
1.2246467991473532e-16
```

The question is, how did the first result end up with -2.0, I might expect it to return something close to zero or an error / nan?

If you are interested in knowing, this equation should give the length (x) of a line that stretches between one point and another point 2 points away in a shape with n equal sides of 1 and all equal angles (the length of the smallest diagonal of an isogon with side length 1).

Comment: sin π is also zero, so no, your first result won’t be zero.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For the second result, the impact is quite small in absolute terms: 1.22464679915e-16 is a very small number and very close to zero, about 0.00000000000000012246

If you simply want to avoid that small error having a large impact in how your results are displayed, use a formatting string, e.g:

```
for i in range(1, 11):
    print "{0:.10f}".format(math.sin(2 * math.pi / i) / math.sin(math.pi / i))
```

output:

```
-2.0000000000
0.0000000000
1.0000000000
1.4142135624
1.6180339887
1.7320508076
1.8019377358
1.8477590650
1.8793852416
1.9021130326
```

> how did the first result end up with -2.0, I might expect it to return something close to zero or an error / nan?

The first result is when i is 1, so it simplifies to:

```
math.sin(2 * math.pi) / math.sin(math.pi)
```

Due to floating point errors, `math.sin(2 * math.pi)` evaluates to `-2.44921270764e-16`, while `math.sin(math.pi)` evaluates to `1.22460635382e-16`.

A floating point division of `-2.44921270764e-16 / 1.22460635382e-16` gives `-2.0`, so that's the final output.

In the absence of floating point errors, both `math.sin(2 * math.pi)` and `math.sin(math.pi)` should have evaluated to zero, but it just so happened by the combined quirks of the floating point implementation and Python sin function implementation that the floating point error of the first was twice that of the second, and negative, so dividing them gave -2.

The floating point error in the internal representation of `math.pi * 2` is twice that of `math.pi` because when you double a value with an error margin the error margin also doubles, and it is not possible to represent pi as a floating point number without some error. Speculation: that error propagates through the sin calculation, and a negative is introduced because of something in the sin calculation related to the fact that the sin function in the range of pi to 2 pi is the negative of the function in the range of 0 to pi.

If you want to round extremely small values to zero, you can use [numpy.around](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.around.html#numpy.around) to round to a given number of decimals, e.g:

```
import numpy
for i in range(1, 11):
    print numpy.around(numpy.sin(2 * numpy.pi / i), 15) / numpy.around(numpy.sin(numpy.pi / i), 15)
```

This produces a nan for the first result.

Comment: I understand how that works already, I just got confused by the first result, which you might expect to give an error or nan, because you divide by sin(π), 0

Comment: can you please edit the answer to reflect the edits in my question, and then I will accept the answer.

Comment: I can see your edits, yet the answer still contains a quote from the original text that has been removed

Comment: @micsthepick ok, removed it

Comment: Thanks. Accepted as answer

Answer (score 2):

These errors are from simple floating point arithmetics... that's just the way this works. So, you can avoid using floating point, but that gives you a lot of pain probably.

If you look at how floating point works [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double-precision_floating-point_format), you'll see that errors will happen... a lot. That's basically the reason why most databases support fixed-point precision for money calculations. That said, sin/cos on fixed point is going to be a pain...

One simple way to avoid these errors is to use a simple pre-calculated lookup table for all (or some of the) 180' angles of sin/cos.

Comment: I know how to handle floats: "I realise that there will be rounding errors, and as such the following results don't surprise me at all:", the problem was the first result gave me -2, when you might expect it to give you an error, and the real mathematical example made me think the result should be 0, and so I thought that somehow dividing the floats had given me a big error.

Comment: Well if you know the error (epsilon), you can simply round after each step. That'll give you back the error and the 0.